# Изменение размеров ImageButton

Tags: android, background

Подскажите, пожалуйста. У меня есть `imagebutton`. На экране их штук 20. Я каждой задаю `Background`. Но `imagebutton` меняет свои размеры. В результате кнопка становится на пол экрана. Но мне нужно, чтобы картинка сжималась по размеру кнопки. Как это реализовать?

```
<TableLayout 

    <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:gravity="center" >

  <ImageButton 
       android:id="@+id/button1" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: добавьте разметку

Comment: <TableLayout 

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

Comment: у вас ImageButton стоит с размерами match_parent и весом 1,  поетому его и растягивает на всю доступную область. попробуйте сделать ему wrap_content без веса

Answer (score 1):

У вас большая картинка, сжимать её нужно в ручную или с помощью утилиты **Image Asset**, доступной в Android Studio.
Ну и в разметке для кнопки:

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```